# How does Push Ups cause one side of my chest to be bigger?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, push-ups

I succeeded in fighting a saggy male chest via standard push ups. When I was working out my lower pecs by incline push ups and finished the routine, I saw the left side of my chest is  bigger than the right side, and I wondered why? I always check my posture and balance before going to do push ups, although I am a left handed person.

Comment: Unless there's a significant difference, don't worry about it; most people have a stronger side and that causes a slight asymmetry in the body physique as well as strength.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether it's normal or not depends on how significant the difference is. It's normal to be slightly asymmetric. No part of your body is *exactly* symmetric.

If it's significant enough for it to bother you, then you should consider doing exercises that are independent for each pec muscle. This is useful because, even though you try to balance it, with a push up or barbell bench, your body can compensate for a weaker side by pushing the weak side up faster. The physics of it makes the weight shift to the lower side. With something like one arm pushups or dumbbell bench, it's impossible to shift weight from one side to the other, so you should have equal development.

To clarify in response to your comment below, you should do this independent exercise equally (same weight, reps and sets) for both sides. This will be easier for the strong side and harder for the weak one, so the weak one will grow more. Not doing so could possibly create imbalances where before you had none. For example, only doing one arm with dumbbell bench could cause an imbalance in your biceps, since the biceps is involved as a stabilizer in db bench.

Comment: You want to do both sides equally. Exercising just the weak side could lead to creating more asymmetry. The way it balances out is that you do the same exercise, with the same reps and weight, for both. This is easier for the strong side, so it grows less (less stimulus) and it's harder for the weak side, so it grows more.

Comment: So, for example, say the 8 rep max of your weak side is 50 lb for dumbbell bench. You could do 8x3 db bench at 50 lb for both arms. Since your strong arm could do 60 lb (for example), 50 lb is easy and it won't get significantly stronger.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that everyone has a dominant pectoral muscle - one which can have greater anchorage on the anterior surface of the sternum.  Often it is the perception that you are able to affect more precise control on one side of your body than the other - it is the mind-body connection at play.

Answer (score -3):

to fix uneven muscle is simple look in the mirror and find out which part of your muscle is bigger or smaller than the other mark that point and hit it with high reps with 4 or 5 set with extreme squeez...improve your weakness part by visualising wat exercise I should do to make this right whatever it takes feel the muscle and pump it..

Comment: if you need to look in the mirror to see the imbalance you have gone a long way through the wrong track